# Should I pass info using intent or use a static variables

Tags: android, android-layout

Another design question for you
If I have 5 activities that can result from one activity
    A->B
    A->C
    A->E
    .... Etc

And activity A has values that need to be passed to all other activites, then do you recommned passing them through intent or should I just have a global static variables in activity A and read the values in any other activity?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitely don't use static public variables.

You should use:

- SharedPreferences or DB for data that should be persisted (cached)
- Intent extras if data is needed in some part of app (couple of activities)
- Application inheritor for application-wide data, that shouldn't be persisted.

Comment: Great answer but not sure why not static variables. Whats the down side?

Comment: It brings you back to stone age of procedural programming, and will cause a mess in any big project.

Comment: Yeah, but if you're one person doing a quick little project, it might save you time and effort without creating spaghetti code. Creating extra work and lines of code purely to avoid "procedural programming" isn't worth it all the time.

Answer (score 2):

You can subclass [android.app.application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) and use that class to share data between activities.

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
  String mySharedString = "Hello World";
}
```

See [How to declare global variables in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables)